# Update inactive TextFields using value from active TextField in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is it possible to bind TextFields to other TextFields in SwiftUI where the value in the active TextField is used to update the values of the inactive TextFields?

In the code below, I would like to input a value of 10 into TextField X and have TextField Y automatically display the number 13 which is 10 + 3. Alternatively, I would like to input 18 into TextField Y and the number 9 would appear in TextField X which is calculated from 18 / 2.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var x = 0.0
    @State private var y = 0.0

    private var numberFormatter: NumberFormatter {
        let numFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        numFormatter.usesSignificantDigits = true
        return numFormatter
    }

    var body: some View {

        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            HStack {
                TextField("Enter X", value: $x, formatter: numberFormatter)
                    .frame(width: 120)
                Text("X where X = Y / 2")
                    .frame(alignment: .leading)
            }
            HStack {
                TextField("Enter Y", value: $y, formatter: numberFormatter)
                    .frame(width: 120)
                Text("Y where Y = X + 3")
                    .frame(alignment: .leading)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 400)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below does what you asked for but note that x and y get updated only *after* the user taps on the keyboard's return button, not automatically.

```swift
TextField("Enter X", value: $x, formatter: numberFormatter, onEditingChanged: { _ in
    self.y = self.x + 3
})
```

```swift
TextField("Enter Y", value: $y, formatter: numberFormatter, onEditingChanged: { _ in
    self.x = self.y / 2
})
```

Comment: The active text field should update the inactive text fields. I edited my question to clarify this.

Comment: If you mean with inactive the one with no focus then it just works. However if you click into the other TextField then it gets calculated again.